# What is a Shady Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Shady Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule:

[image]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

Shady Words™,Not Shady Words™
BELT,CORD
BLOCK,BRICK
DRESS,GLASSES
DRIED,WETTED
HAT,COAT
LESS,MORE
LIT,MATH
SET,SPOT

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said my previous answer, prefixing with "SUN", was close (and actually worked until the Not Shady Words™ list was changed to preclude this answer).

While various dictionaries don't quite agree with each other about this new attempt, it is close to what I had before and most of the word lists I use agree with me so I'm going to give this a go ...

> Shady Words™ can be prefixed with "UN" to form new words.

And they're shady because

> they can be turned to the dark side (negated).

Comment: Close, but no cigar, I'm afraid. I realise now I haven't made the puzzle specific enough. I'll modify a few of the words to rule out this specific answer.

Comment: man. I was sure on that one, it fit perfectly - even the name. :)

Comment: You're close, Rubio. Have another look...

Comment: Wouldn't Glasses and Spot be shady?

Comment: OP paolo changed the question because my answer was not what he was looking for.  "glasses" was formerly "skirt" and "spot" formerly "group", for which my answer worked; it doesn't anymore, so .. back to the drawing board

Comment: Surely a valid answer is a valid answer even if not the originally intended one?

Comment: @Rubio, I'm giving you this one. Words on the left can be modified as described in your original and current answers to make two new words, while ones on the right cannot. The explanation of the title should follow on from this.

Comment: @paolo thank you - what was the intended rule?

Comment: @Rubio The rule was that the words on the left can each be prefixed by UN and SUN to make new words ("shady" meaning "not sunny", which hints at UN- and SUN). Words on the left cannot be transformed in this way. It was necessary for me to include a few SUN... words on the right to show that it wasn't just UN or SUN that could be added. My bad for letting this slip through when I originally posted the puzzle.